# Does texlive-scheme-full in Fedora 38 come with a ready set of templates?

Tags: texlive, templates, linuxfedora

I ran `sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full` in Fedora 38, and it downloaded 2.6 GB of files. Surely, there must be ready-to-use templates among those files, but I cannot seem to find them.

Do I have to download templates separately?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you call a template? The most simple *template* in LaTeX would be a *class*. And there are a lot of classes in `texlive-scheme-full`, AFAIK several hundred. They all are ready to use. Most of the classes also have manuals, several of them also contain examples.

Comment: "template" usually just means an example document, eg a journal might provide a "template" of a journal article, an example article, but latex has nothing called template and you don't need to download any template to use latex.

Comment: By `template` I mean a sample article, or sample book with chapters, etc. For example, MiKTeX has a whole bunch of those, so that I can get started on a new document simply by selecting one of those samples and editing it.

Comment: Then you will find those in a full TeX Live installation too, except for cases with unclear license. Try `tlmgr search --all 'template|example|sample'` at the command line. It lists everything containing "template" or "example" or "sample" in a package name, package description or filename.

Comment: The sources of the packages and classes also contain the sources of the manuals (→ `…/texmf-dist/source/…`). So there are several thousand more examples than only the examples … ;-)